# Get UAC settings using powershell

Tags: powershell

Is there a way to get the UAC status(including level) in windows 7 computer using powershell?

Answer (score 15):

```
(Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System).EnableLUA
```

will tell u if UAC is enabled or not.

Comment: You could also pull it out as a Boolean depending on your need, e.g.[bool]((Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System).EnableLUA))

Answer (score 1):

The UAC level is recorded in system register keys. You can use the code below to get them.

```
$Key = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System" 
$ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin_Name = "ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin" 
$PromptOnSecureDesktop_Name = "PromptOnSecureDesktop" 

$ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin_Value = Get-RegistryValue $Key $ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin_Name 
$PromptOnSecureDesktop_Value = Get-RegistryValue $Key $PromptOnSecureDesktop_Name
```

Different combinations between $ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin_Value and $PromptOnSecureDesktop_Valued defines the UAC level.

For the complete sample, you can refer to https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/How-to-switch-UAC-level-0ac3ea11

Answer (score 1):

The answer from eric good but need the function Get-RegistryValue declared. So first you need to:

```
Function Get-RegistryValue($key, $value) {  (Get-ItemProperty $key $value).$value }
```

Then you can get the settings as he described:

```
$Key = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System" 
$ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin_Name = "ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin" 
$PromptOnSecureDesktop_Name = "PromptOnSecureDesktop" 

$ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin_Value = Get-RegistryValue $Key $ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin_Name 
$PromptOnSecureDesktop_Value = Get-RegistryValue $Key $PromptOnSecureDesktop_Name
```

Then you can interpret the values with:

```
If($ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin_Value -Eq 0 -And $PromptOnSecureDesktop_Value -Eq 0){ 
    "Never notIfy" 
} 
ElseIf($ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin_Value -Eq 5 -And $PromptOnSecureDesktop_Value -Eq 0){ 
    "NotIfy me only when apps try to make changes to my computer(do not dim my desktop)" 
} 
ElseIf($ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin_Value -Eq 5 -And $PromptOnSecureDesktop_Value -Eq 1){ 
    "NotIfy me only when apps try to make changes to my computer(default)" 
} 
ElseIf($ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin_Value -Eq 2 -And $PromptOnSecureDesktop_Value -Eq 1){ 
    "Always notIfy" 
} 
Else{ 
    "Unknown" 
}
```

From [How to switch UAC level](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/How-to-switch-UAC-level-0ac3ea11).

Answer (score 0):

@ravikanth already posted a good answer, but for those exploring other options here are two other ways to get the same info in different way:

```
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System -Name EnableLUA
```

or

```
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System -Name EnableLUA | Select-Object EnableLUA
```